# Infer type from nested STL template

Tags: c++, templates, stl

How to I get my class to infer the inner type of a parameter without explicitly referring to it? Look at the minimal example below:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T> 
class foo {
public:
  foo(std::vector<T> &x) :
    _x(x) {
      T dummy = x.front(); // Trying to trick the compiler here
   }
private:
  std::vector<T> _x;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a;
  foo<int> b(a);  // This works
  foo c(a);       // This fails
  return 0;
}
```

I see that `foo` expects it's argument to be a `vector<int>`, but it let's me create an object of type `T==[int]` so it seems like it knows what the inner type is! Neverminding the fact that the assignment of `dummy` fails when `a` is empty ... how can I refer to the nested inner type?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "nested inner type"? Where is the nested template? Where do you want the type to be inferred? The line `foo c(a)`, or somewhere else?

Comment: @jalf Sorry if the wording is unclear, or if I've confused my terms (please correct me). I'd like to make the line `foo c(a)` compile, whereas now it fails since `foo` doesn't have a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo c(a);       // This fails
```

For obvious reasons. `foo` is a class template, you cannot instantiate an object of it without naming a template parameter.
This is not like a function template, where the template arguments can be inferred through the function arguments. `foo` in this case names a type (or should), not the constructor.

In C++11, you might do this:

```
template<class T>
foo<T> make_foo(std::vector<T> const& x){
  return foo<T>(x);
}

// in main
auto f = make_foo(a);
```

Comment: Along those lines then, can you wrap the construction in a function and just use the new `auto` to return the type? Is this standard practice?

Comment: @Hooked: That you can do in C++11, sure. I'm not so sure if it's useful, though. But you can do it, no problem.

Comment: Actually you can't *return* an `auto` as it's a placeholder for a type. The type of `auto` will be deduced during initialization so it can't be used as a return type or as a parameter.

Comment: @AJG: Oh, I didn't interpret the comment like that, as you can see in my edit. Good point though.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point that out for @Hooked to be clear ;-)